# Preview Google Sheets email before sending?

Tags: email, google-sheets, scripting, preview

I have a nicely working Google Script that takes data from my Google Sheets and sends out the information as an HTML email.  Works great, but I would LOVE to be able to simply preview the email before sending.

It must be possible to show the HTML in the sidebar or pop-up window?

I am sure the answer is in the `HtmlService.createHtmlOutput` coding, but I can't seem to make it work.

Can anyone help by offering a coding example?

Ideally, the pop-up window that allows me to look at it, then a button to Send would be great.

My email code that I'd love to preview (email reply details removed):

```
var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

function sendEmails3() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('LateEmail');
  var startRow = 3;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 45;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 40)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
    var message = row[8]+row[9]+row[10]+row[11]+row[12]+row[13]+row[14]+row[15]+row[16]+row[17]+row[18]+row[19]+row[20]+row[21]+row[22]+row[23]+row[24]+row[25]+row[26]+row[27]+row[28]+row[29]+row[30]+row[31]+row[32]+row[33]+row[34]+row[35]+row[36]+row[37];       // Second column
    var emailSent = row[7];     // Third column
            if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {  // Prevents sending duplicates
      var subject = "Assignments for Tomorrow";
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {
        name: 'Assignments',
        replyTo: 'assignments@****.com',
        htmlBody: message
      });
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 8).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a simple HTML page and insert the email body into it to then approve.  You may want to start [here: Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets) and then look at [HTML Service: Create and Serve HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/) as a starting point.

Once you have specific questions, create a new post and be sure to include your code.